# Optimal scheduling order for two queues of jobs

Tags: algorithm

I have two queues of jobs and each job consists of the pair (utilization %, time to complete). I have one machine and its utilization cannot exceed 100%. The first job in a queue must be completed before the second one can be started (and so on). What is an algorithm to find the best schedule for these jobs so that the total time is minimized?

Comment: I believe in this case, [EDF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling) would be optimal?

Comment: I don't see how deadline in the algorithm you linked would be used here. "time to complete" in this sense is how long it takes the machine to complete the job.

Comment: You might get more insightful answers on [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You are right, they are not quite the same. Is utilization percent an integer? May be able to map this to a well known sceduling problem involving 100 different machines _per_ utilization percent.